# SQL query using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table in MySQL with three columns that need an average of each row of three columns using the stored procedure:

```
Id  |  One  |  Two  |  Three
----+-------+-------+-------
1   |  10   |  30   |  20
2   |  50   |  60   |  20
3   |  60   |  0    |  40
```

The average must be determined using a stored procedure, not a normal query.

I have this SQL query

```
select
    id, 
    (ifnull(one, 0) + ifnull(two, 0) + ifnull(three, 0)) /
        ((one is not null) + (two is not null) + (three is not null)) as average 
from table
```

I want that to look like this, with a MySQL query:

```
Id | Average
---+--------
1  | 20
2  | 43.3
3  | 50
```

Comment: why answer deleted?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am a student I don't know basic things. learning now sorry if i am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution but you could use:

```
select id, 
       SUM(coalesce(one,0)+coalesce(two,0)+coalesce(three,0)) /
       count(CASE WHEN one != 0 and one is not null  then 1 ELSE NULL END) 
       + count(CASE WHEN two != 0 and two is not null  then 1 ELSE NULL END) 
       + count(CASE WHEN three  != 0 and three is not null  then 1 ELSE NULL END )  as average 

from my_table
group by id;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> id    average
> 1     20.0000
> 2     43.3333
> 3     50.0000
> 4     35.0000
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fbc0108ae1c617a0cdc7978007eb0307)

**This query excludes `Null` and `0` values**

[coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Full Procedure

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE average()
BEGIN 

    select id, SUM(coalesce(one,0)+coalesce(two,0)+coalesce(three,0)) /(count(CASE WHEN one != 0 and one is not null  then 1 ELSE NULL END) + count(CASE WHEN two != 0 and two is not null  then 1 ELSE NULL END) + count(CASE WHEN three  != 0 and three is not null  then 1 ELSE NULL END))  as average from my_table group by id ;

END
DELIMITER ;
```